# 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

It's been hours that I'm trying to fix this issue, but I cant resolve it:

The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
}
```

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: If you use a library that does not use androidx still then you wont be able to use that library until it does

Comment: Im not using other libraries, I replaced all by androidx.*

Comment: if you are not using any libraries then why are you using the `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0` dependency

Comment: i deleted androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 but still hve the same problem